# Prove that $\| A^{-1} u\|_H\le \| A^{-1}\|_H \|u\|_H,$ where $A$ is a self adjoint operator and $H$ Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space and let $A$ be a self adjoint operator such that $A^{-1}$ is compact. It is left as an exercise, to find and example of such an operator $A$. I was thinking about the Laplace operator $(-\Delta)$ on the Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega)$ with $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is an open bounded subspace. I am just a bit in bind because I don't know if $(-\Delta)^{-1}$ is compact. Could someone please give me a reference about that?

Finally, in the previous hypotheses, it is also required to show that
$$\| A^{-1} u\|_H\le \| A^{-1}\|_H \|u\|_H.$$

Could someone please help me to prove that the above inequality holds true?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Presumably you want $H$ to be infinite-dimensional. In finite dimensions all linear operators are compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, see this: [Under which circumstances is the Laplacian compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114947/under-which-circumstances-is-the-laplacian-compact)

You can also find proofs of this in many PDE books such as Michael Taylor's first PDE book (Proposition 1.2 in chapter 5). Essentially, if you can show that it's bounded from $H^{-1}(\Omega)\rightarrow H_0^1(\Omega)$, then you just restrict the domain to $L^2(\Omega)$ and use Rellich's theorem to compactly embed the range into $L^2(\Omega)$.

For your second question (and the title question), compact operators are bounded, and it is always true that if $L$ is bounded on $H$, then $$\|Lu\|_H\leq\|L\|_{op}\|u\|_H,$$ where $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ denotes the operator norm on $H$. This follows directly from the definition of the operator norm; there are many equivalent definitions of the operator norm, such as $$\|L\|_{op}=\sup_{u\neq 0}\frac{\|Lu\|_H}{\|u\|_H}.$$ You can see it immediately from here.